# can anyone show me how and How they have 5 button on the title bar instead of 3 max, resize, close in Windows?

Tags: windows, button, operating-system

mostly in all article i found that everyone show that their OS give them 5 button. can anyone explain how

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc3-part1-cs

in this article every window's title bar have 5 button on top whenever i can see only three button in my windows [close, restore ,maximize].

can anyone show me reason behind  it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're running [**UltraMon**](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/), which is a utility that provides enhancements for multiple monitor support.

In particular, it adds extra window management buttons to the title bars of all applications, which make it easy to move windows from screen to screen.

[image: Title bar buttons added by UltraMon]                                  [image: Other sample of title bar buttons added by UltraMon]

You can [download a free evaluation version](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/download.asp) from the vendor, but the full version will cost you $39.95 US.

Answer (score 0):

He has multiple screens on his computer, those buttons mean move to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

Extra buttons in the titlebar come from utility applications that hook into every process.

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/custom-titlebar) for a basic example, you also need to register a hook with [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (WH_CBT or WH_SHELL)

Comment: @Cody: Yes, I know it does not work with XP Luna or DWM, that is why I called it a basic tutorial...

Comment: Fair enough. I don't think that makes it "basic", though. Most people take DWM for granted nowadays, with it enabled out-of-the-box on all modern versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Vista and 7, Microsoft has provided detailed guidance in the article [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195(v=vs.85).aspx).

Copied from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558118/tabs-in-title-bar-whats-the-secret/5587680#5587680).